# Here I want 100% height in my bottom section and I don't want exceed what I fixed 400px height in “.main” class

Tags: html, css

[image]I am getting problem with 100% height in my design bottom section. Here I want 100% height in my bottom section and I don't want exceed what I fixed 400px height in “.main” class. and i dont want move height of top section.i want only bottom section 100% all the time.

Can you check here : http://jsfiddle.net/jZTr2/2/

I dont want to move top blue highlighted section. And I want 100% height bottom chat section.

Comment: you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jZTr2/3/

Comment: No. With you code also i am getting the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/jZTr2/4/    it was overlapping...

Comment: can you create a simple image in paint/similar app and display what exactly you need?

Comment: @Omm Some thing like this.. http://jsfiddle.net/jZTr2/5/

Comment: But ".main" class height should not 100%. it should be px. if i change height of main class, bottom section height will fix 100%;

Comment: @Chasing Death plz find the image. here i am want chat room 100% all time. but main window having px height not %.

Comment: @Omm just try this one... http://jsfiddle.net/jZTr2/6/

Comment: @Omm or try this one... http://jsfiddle.net/jZTr2/9/

Comment: Please reply to this: The div with actions button is `topSection` and the chat comes in `bottomSection`?

Comment: @naim shaikh  almost working but if i increase the with of main class i am finding somewhat gap in bottom section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/jZTr2/12/

The secret is `display:table` and `display:table-row`. Note that you may need to customize the width a bit for your implementation.

Comment: No problem. Good luck on your site!

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will work.   http://jsfiddle.net/jZTr2/10/